# How get record for this specific case?

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have three tables

```
Person (id, name, email)
Address (id, Person_id, address, verified)
Person_Claimed (id, Person_id, name, email)
```

We add records in Person and Address table manually. When someone see his/her profile online, he/she claimed his/her profile and a entry is created in Person_Claimed Table.

Now I want to get records of persons who have not claimed their profiles AND also their addresses are not verified.

How to join these tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `verified` is not null and 0 means 'not verified'

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Address a ON (a.Person_id = p.id )
LEFT JOIN Person_Claimed pc ON (pc.Person_id = p.id)
WHERE a.verified =0 AND pc.id IS NULL
```

If person can have multiple not verified addresses, you may want to add `GROUP BY p.id`  (or `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `SELECT`

Comment: `pc.id IS NULL` in query means that person does not exists in `Person_Claimed` table ?